# How to find maximum value/s in a 2D Arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to rewrite an old program by using Arraylists instead of just arrays. The program was a database of the top 5 video game sales in 2017, and one of the methods the program does is finding the maximum values per location (4 locations in all: NA, EU, JP, & Other Sales).

(Note: There are 5 columns of sales in all (NA, EU, JP, Other Sales, Global Sales), and I only wanted the method to find the maximum values in the first four columns.)

These are snippets of the 2D array and its corresponding method for finding the maximum values:

```
double[][] Sales ={ {41.49,29.02,3.77,8.46,82.74},{29.08,3.58,6.81,0.77,40.24},
        {15.85,12.88,3.79,3.31,35.83},{15.75,11.01,3.28,2.96,33},
        {11.27,8.89,10.22,1,31.38} };


// maximum value
public static void hiSales(double[][] sales) {
    double max1;
    double[] max = new double[sales.length];
    for(int j=0; j<sales[0].length-1;j++) { //WILL WORK AS LONG AS IT IS SQUARE MATRIX
        
        for (int i = 0; i < sales.length; i++) {
            max1 = sales[0][j];
            if (sales[i][j] > max1) {
                max1 = sales[i][j];
            }
            if (i == sales.length - 1) {
                max[j] = max1;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n                | HIGHEST SALES PER LOCATION |");
    System.out.println("\n | NA Sales |    | EU Sales |    | JP Sales |   "
            + "| Other Sales |   \n");
    System.out.println("— — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — —\n");
    System.out.print("     ");
    for(int i=0; i<max.length-1; i++) {
        System.out.print(max[i] + "\t");
        System.out.print("     ");
    } 
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("— — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — —");
}
```

Now, I've converted the 2D array into a 2D Arraylist, and the method cannot function anymore, which is the problem I would like to address.

This is the new 2D Arraylist I've converted:

```
ArrayList<VGSdata> sales = new ArrayList<>();
VGSdata wii = new VGSdata(41.49,29.02,3.77,8.46,82.74);
VGSdata bros = new VGSdata(29.08,3.58,6.81,0.77,40.24);
VGSdata kart = new VGSdata(15.85,12.88,3.79,3.31,35.83);
VGSdata res = new VGSdata(15.75,11.01,3.28,2.96,33);
VGSdata prb = new VGSdata(11.27,8.89,10.22,1,31.38);
    
sales.add(wii);
sales.add(bros);
sales.add(kart);
sales.add(res);
sales.add(prb);
```

So.. how will the method be rewritten in order for it to utilize the data in the `ArrayList` while still performing the same function?

Comment: how does it not work? all you need to do is change the `array[index]` to `yourArrayList.get(index)` and if you are getting from an embedded array, it would be `yourArrayList.get(index).get(otherIndex)`

Comment: You've made a 1D ArrayList, not a 2D one here. A '2D' ArrayList would be of type `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>`?

Comment: @RIVERMAN2010 indeed, I thought that was simply what I had to do, but when I do `array.get(i).get(j)` , the `.get(j)` shows an error saying "cannot find symbol", and it sees it as a method that I would then have to create. Is there any explanation why it's like that?

Comment: @HenryTwist pardon me, I don't quite get what you mean. I tried retyping it to what you wrote, but it then shows a bunch of errors. i thought it was already fine as is, since I created a method to simply display the arraylist and it works just fine.

Comment: Your normal array is an array of an array of doubles right? But then your ArrayList is not an ArrayList of an ArrayList of Doubles, but an ArrayList of `VGSData`. So your two problems are not equivalent.

Comment: @HenryTwist Indeed. I can see how that may be the problem. The `VGSdata` is a separate class I made that performs the methods for displaying the said arraylist. This is the contents of the class: [link](https://imgur.com/a/BsNvIRU) Is there a way to get around/resolve this?

Comment: @Viole even though not related to the issue, `max1 = sales[0][j];` why is this written inside the inner `for` loop?

Comment: Well instead of being able to loop through the inner values, you would have to retrieve fields from the class one by one using your getters. If you're looking to loop through the fields then I would consider using a `List` instead!

Comment: @GauthamM To store the values/variables, I presume? Truth to be told, some parts of the method including that was the work of a friend, and it works perfectly well to how I wanted it to perform.

Comment: @HenryTwist Thank you for your suggestion, sir. Truth to be told, I am just a beginner in the programming world and I'm just learning about ArrayLists currently. With that being said, I hope you can pardon me since I barely understand how I am able to apply your suggestion.

Comment: @Viole That is actually a bug. `max1 = sales[0][j];` should be done just above the inner loop. This code would work only if the highest score is either in the first array or the last array.
Try putting this `{11.27,8.89,10.22,1,31.38}` (currently last) in the second last position and put `{15.75,11.01,3.28,2.96,33}` (currently second last) as the last array. You would get wrong result with the current code.

Comment: @GauthamM I did what u said, and it made one error, which is it showed a wrong result under the JP Sales Column. I'll gladly apply your suggestion then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to rewrite the `hiSales` method then you could create a 2d array from the arraylist and then pass it on to the `hiSales` method.

```java
double[][] dataArray = new double[sales.size()][4];
int i=0;
for(VGSdata data : sales) {
    dataArray[i][0] = data.displayNA();
    dataArray[i][1] = data.displayEU();
    dataArray[i][2] = data.displayJP();
    dataArray[i][3] = data.displayOS();

    i++;
}

// now invoke hiSales
hiSales(dataArray);
```

Comment: I actually just thought of a similar method like this, so I really appreciate it. It might actually work.

Comment: @Viole make sure that the statement i mentioned is in the right place. I had added a comment as explanation against the question.